# Enable php modules in php:php-fpm docker image

Tags: php, docker

How'd I enable a PHP module in official [`php:php-fpm`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.3/buster/fpm/Dockerfile) docker image? Cannot install `php-zip` for instance:

```
root@122f1612f817:/var/www/html# apt-cache policy php-zip
php-zip:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: (none)
Version table:
    2:7.3+69 -1
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages

root@122f1612f817:/var/www/html# apt-get install php-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-zip is a virtual package provided by:
php7.3-zip 7.3.4-2 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'php-zip' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Can you try 'zip' instead of 'php-zip'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install it as a PHP extension as it seems from the logs it not available in the repo.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libzip-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Answer (score -1):

add line to Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install php-zip  -y
```

Answer (score -1):

**php-zip for PHP >= 7.3**

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```